# adjusting speed of turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm wondering if there's any way to adjust the speed of turtlebot. It's moving too fast for my preference.

I'm using a logitech dual action game pad. I can move it perfectly fine when I press button 5 and the arrow keys, except that the speed is really fast and it gets jerky when I press and let go.

Is there any way to get the right joystick of the game pad to control turtlebot. It seems that the right joystick is able to vary its speed depending on how far you move it. Otherwise, I would be happy if someone could teach me at least how to reduce the maximum speed.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10434/adjusting-speed-of-turtlebot/) by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2011-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I presume you are using the turtlebot_teleop package within the turtlebot_apps stack? If so, you should be able to edit the turtlebot_teleop/joystick_teleop.launch file. If you open the file, you'll find a line like:

```
<param name="scale_linear" value="0.5"/>
```

Reduce the 0.5 to slow the turtlebot's top speed.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on 2011-06-29**:
Yes I am. Thank you!